# Plot piecewise symbolic function

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

So, this is my script:

```
syms t r w
x1=5^-t*heaviside(t);
x_2=subs(x1,t,t-r);
x2=conj(x_2);
R=int(x1*x2,t,-inf,inf);
R=simplify(R)

ezplot(R, [-10 10]);
```

`R=piecewise([0 <= r, 1/5^r/(2*log(5))], [r <= 0, 5^r/(2*log(5))])`

And as you can see I am trying to plot symbolic solution with `ezplot` function but I get this error:

```
The input string must be an expression.  Implicit functions of a single variable are not supported.
```

As I understand matlab doesn't work with piecewise functions. Is there any other way I can plot this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the approach of rewriting the piecewise expression with ineqalities:

```
ezplot(@(r)(0 <= r)*1/5^r/(2*log(5)) + (r <= 0)*5^r/(2*log(5)));
```

Not ideal with the copy-paste, but it's better than nothing.

Alternatively you can evaluate this numerically:

```
x = -10:0.01:10;
y = eval(subs(R,r,x));
plot(x,y)
```